# Multivariate taylor to an expansion of Newton-Raphson.

Tags: taylor-expansion, newton-raphson

Multivariate Taylor with 2 parts:
$$\vec F(\vec x)=\vec F(\vec a)+\nabla\vec F(\vec a)\cdot(\vec x-\vec a)$$
Inverse Taylor which is the multivariate Newton-Raphson method:
$$\vec x =\vec a + (\nabla \vec F(\vec a))^{-1}\cdot(\vec F(\vec x)-\vec F(\vec a))$$

Multivariate Taylor with 3 parts:
$$\vec F(\vec x)=\vec F(\vec a)+\nabla\vec F(\vec a)\cdot(\vec x-\vec a)+\frac 1 2 \{\nabla[\nabla\vec F(\vec a)\cdot (\vec x-\vec a)]\cdot (\vec x-\vec a)\}$$
which become using $\nabla(a\cdot b)=\nabla a\cdot b+a\cdot\nabla b$:
$$\vec F(\vec x)=\vec F(\vec a)+\frac 3 2\nabla\vec F(\vec a)\cdot(\vec x-\vec a)+\frac 1 2 [\nabla(\nabla\vec F(\vec a))\cdot (\vec x-\vec a)]\cdot (\vec x-\vec a)$$
which gives a tensor of rank 3.

Now, I want an expansion to Newton-Raphson, which use all of Taylor parts. How can I solve for $(\vec x-\vec a)$ ?

If this was single-dimensional will be something like:
$$x = \frac{-f'(a)+a f''(a)\pm\sqrt{f'(a)^2+2(f(x)-f(a))f''(a)}}{f''(a)}$$
but with such tensor algebra, I cannot solve.

Can you help please?

Comment: Since multi-d Newton-Raphson already converges superlinearly, there is really no interest in using higher Taylor approximations. Not much would be gained.

Comment: What means superlinearly? How multiple of a matrix $(\nabla\vec F(\vec a))^{-1}$ with a vector $(\vec F(\vec x)-\vec F(\vec a))$ is something bigger than linear?

Comment: Linear convergence means that each iteration step adds roughly the same number of correct digits to the approximate solution. So the number of correct digits is proportional to the number of steps of the iteration.  Superlinear convergence means that the increment of correct digits in each step increases to infinity. So the number of correct digits grows faster than the number of iteration steps. For the Newton-Raphson method, the number of correct digits roughly doubles with each iteration step. This is called quadratic convergence. http://www.math.unl.edu/~s-bbockel1/833-notes/node7.html